# How to add additional lines across the graph on the Y Axis

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

PowerBI automatically builds graphs based on my data, but often times it will have few (or ZERO) horizontal lines going accross the Y Axis.  It makes it very difficult to see where the data is landing across my graph.  I would like to add additional lines and numers recorded along the Y axis here but so no way to do it.

How can I add more granularity to labels on the Y axis, including lines going across horizontally?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Power BI doesn't yet have the ability to control the number of gridlines used. In the meantime, you could use either the constant lines in the Analytics Pane to put in additional lines or turn on data labels.

Comment: Any plans in the future that you know of?